# Customize Shared Documents upload form in Infopath

Tags: infopath

Is there any way to customize the Sharepoint Shared Documents' "Add document" form using infopath? We need to do a couple lookups against other lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has an article here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2008/07/18/custom-upload-page-in-layouts-for-document-library-and-it-s-navigation-from-upload-menu-in-the-toolbar-bend-it-custom-upload-menu-for-the-document-library.aspx

Comment: Any specific help towards targeting this for infopath?

Comment: You'll have to publish an infopath form, and use the URL for your custom upload page.  You can still customize the menu to remove the old link and add a link to your new URL.  You'll need a InfoPath form with custom code to load a file from InforPath.  Here is an article on that: http://knrs.blogspot.com/2007/11/upload-infopath-attachment-to-document.html.

Answer (score 1):

Add lookup columns to the list and after the item is uploaded, the metadata will be available to be set.